# What are the Hebrew words for Man and Woman?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, creation

I was reading through Genesis where it notes:

> "she shall be called 'woman' for she was taken out of 'man'" - Genesis 2:23 (NIV)

I found out that man is 'Adam' in Hebrew and now I'm wondering what the Hebrew word for woman is to delve further into this passage. Any idea?

Comment: Tangentially related: [Why do the references to Eve change from “woman” to “wife” without any explanation?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/19028/3555)

Comment: Peripherally related: [Are the words “wife” and “woman” the same in Hebrew and Greek?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13624/2215)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hebrew word for man is אָדָם (*adam*) or אּישׁ (*ish*).  The "out of man" (מֵאִ֖ישׁ *meish*, also transliterated *me’iysh*) in this passage derives from the latter form.  Like in Gen 2:23, *ish* often carries a definite connection with males (as opposed to "mankind"), but has a variety of uses.  You can explore the usage of all forms of *ish* [here](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/376.htm) and *meish* [here](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/meish_376.htm).  Usage of *adam*, which more commonly means mankind as a whole than males only, can be found [here](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/120.htm).

The Hebrew word for woman is אִשָּׁ֔ה (*ishshah*, also transliterated ishah). It normally means woman, female, or wife. You can explore the usage of all forms of *ishshah* [here](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/802.htm) and the root form (As used in Gen 2:23) specifically [here](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/ishshah_802.htm)